# Можно ли переписать этот код покрасивее?

Tags: golang, инспекция-кода

Решал задачу из [курса](https://stepik.org/course/54403/) на Stepik:

> По данному трехзначному числу определите, все ли его цифры различны.
>
> **Формат входных данных**
>
> На вход подается одно натуральное трехзначное число.
>
> **Формат выходных данных**
>
> Выведите "YES", если все цифры числа различны, в противном случае - "NO".

Я написал такой код (полностью рабочий, все правильно решает):

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num, a, b, c int
    
    fmt.Scan(&num)
    
    a = num % 10
    b = num % 100 / 10
    c = num % 1000 / 100
    
    if a == b || a == c || b == c {
        fmt.Println("NO")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("YES")
    }
}
```

Но он получился не очень красивый (`a == b || a == c || b == c`), даже немного запутанный.

Как это можно сделать покрасивее? Я думаю можно что-нибудь с массивами сделать, но я пока ещё новичок в GoLang, и поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: @АндрейNOP а почему вы убрали последнюю строку?

Comment: Потому что она не имеет отношения к вопросу

Comment: @АндрейNOP ладно, хорошо.

Comment: Вполне нормальный код для заведомо трехзначного числа. С массивами можно, если нужна универсальность для чисел любой длины. Псевдокод: `array = []; while (num > 0) { array.push(num % 10); num = num / 10; } if (array.distinct().length != array.length) { print('no'); }`

Comment: И ещё вариант, завести булевый массив на 10 элементов и перебирать цифры. Если в массиве соответствующее значение false, то выставляем его true. А если уже true, то значит такая цифра уже встречалась и можно на этом остановиться и сообщить результат.

Comment: на мой взгляд, код `(a == b || a == c || b == c)` для конкретного случая прекрасен и понятен

Comment: @MBo да этот код в этом случае нормален, но если число будет из 9 или 10 цифр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел, наверное самое лаконичное решение:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num int
    var seen [10]bool
    
    for {
        _, err := fmt.Scanf("%1d", &num)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("YES")
            break
        } else if seen[num] {
            fmt.Println("NO")
            break
        }

        seen[num] = true
    }
}
```

Comment: разве это красивее?

Comment: @Эникейщик Не красивее кода в вопросе, но думаю красивее кодов в ответе. И ещё, этот код работает для любой длинны, а не для 3. И вы подумайте какой код придется писать если число из 9 цифр?

Comment: @Эникейщик кстати, поздравляю с достижением 25k! ✨

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без бессмысленного использования строк, хештаблиц или динамических массивов. Посимвольное чтение с окончанием работы при нахождении первого повтора.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var seen [10] bool
    for {
        var char rune
        fmt.Scanf("%c", &char)
        if char < '0' || '9' < char {
            fmt.Println("YES")
            break
        }
        var index = int(char - '0')
        if seen[index] {
            fmt.Println("NO")
            break
        }
        seen[index] = true
    }
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/vfhnfdfbh)

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю как вот это работает: `char < '0' || '9' < char`... То есть если это не число! Объясните пожалуйста!

Comment: `rune` это целочисленный тип со значением, согласно коду символа в юникоде. Соответственно в этом условии проверяется, прочиталась ли очередная цифра, либо они закончились и тогда надо заканчивать.

Answer (score 1):

полирнем ;)

- в предположении, что число положительное, не содержит лидирующих
  нулей и помещается в *int*

```
package main

import "fmt"

func allDigitsDifferent(num int) bool {
    var seen int
    for num > 0 {
        dig := 1 << (num % 10)
        if seen & dig != 0 {
            return false
        }
        seen |= dig
        num /= 10
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    var num int
    fmt.Scan(&num)
    
    if allDigitsDifferent(num) {
        fmt.Println("YES")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("NO")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить идеологически другой вариант - читаем строку, преобразуем в  массив чисел, добавляем эти числа в мапу в качестве ключа и если размер мапы равен размеру массива (в вашем случае 3), то все числа уникальные.

```
func main() {
    
    var num string
    fmt.Scan(&num)
    arr := strings.Split(num, "")
    m := map[string]struct{}{}
    
    for _, v := range arr {
        m[v] = struct{}{}
    }
    
    if len(m) != len(arr) {
        fmt.Println("NO")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("YES")
    }
    
}
```

UPD
небольшая оптимизация по совету @Кирилл Новгородцев:
перед добавлением ключа в мапу идёт проверка на наличие ключа - если таковой имеется то фиксируем что дубликат существует и прерываем цикл

```
func main() {
    
    var num string
    fmt.Scan(&num)
    m := map[string]struct{}{}
    result := "YES"
    
    for _, v := range strings.Split(num, "") {
        if _, ok := m[v]; ok {
            result = "NO"
            break;
        }
        m[v] = struct{}{}
    }
    
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Не знаю голанг, по этому не могу написать код, но это алгорим можно улучшить: перед добавлением нового ключа в хэш (очевидно, мапой вы называли хэш), проверять его наличие. Если такой ключ уже есть, выходить с признаком дубля, если нет - продолжать добавление. Если получилось добавить все ключи - значит дублей нет.

В качестве хэша можно использовать разряженный массив, индексы которого выступают ключами.

Comment: соглашусь с претензией, но при этом код немного разрастётся и может выйти за пределы понимания для учебного задания.

Comment: А разве этот код красивее или понятнее?

Comment: @Serodv не могу, поэтому вопрос и задал :)

Comment: А почему минус?